# changeItemTpl dynamically depending data jsonStore

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am a beginner in the classic of Sencha ExtJS!

I need to change the content to dataview itemTpl.

**Here is my data from jsonstore:**

```
{
    success: true,
    items: {
        idTipoActividad: 1,
        Ejercicios: [{
            idimgCorrect: 1,
            nameAudio: 'brother-in-law',
            images: [{
                id: 1,
                filename: 'https://www.abc.es/Media/201308/01/1--644x362.jpg'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                filename: 'https://www.abc.es/Media/201308/01/1--644x362.jpg'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                filename: 'https://www.abc.es/Media/201308/01/1--644x362.jpg'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                filename: 'https://www.abc.es/Media/201308/01/1--644x362.jpg'
            }]
        }, {
            idimgCorrect: 2,
            nameAudio: 'Home',
            images: [{
                id: 1,
                filename: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/SEAT_600_SIAM_2008.JPG'
            }, {
                id: 2,
                filename: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/SEAT_600_SIAM_2008.JPG'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                filename: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/SEAT_600_SIAM_2008.JPG'
            }, {
                id: 4,
                filename: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/SEAT_600_SIAM_2008.JPG'
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

The array Ejercicios should to change with click button and show in itemTpl
Here is my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tpl` instead of `itemTpl` and attach below function to `dataview`:

```
setTemplate: function (template, itemSelector) {
    this.tpl = template;
    this.itemSelector = itemSelector;
    this.refresh();
}
```

and use it in your `onBtnNextClick1` function like below:

```
refs.viewImages.setTemplate(tpl, 'div.container');
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jsq)

**Note:**  Please check `AudioImagen3.js` and `MyWindow3ViewController4.js` in [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2jsq) for detailed info. (I have corrected couple of code too.)

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!... It works perfectly!! another question. 
That it is more optimal to work with tpl or sencha components, based on data from jsonstore. Suppose there would be up to 50 exercises.